# how to call function of iframe from the button in lightbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, joomla

I have a little problem while calling the JS function which is defined in iframe source from the light box. Here is my code what i tried so far,

**index.php**

```
<iframe id="commentframe" src="index.php?option=com_excelvision&view=livevideo&layout=commentiframe&tmpl=component2&ev_id=<?php echo $result[0]->id;?>" width="950px" height="450px"></iframe>
```

**commnentframe.php**

```
<script>
function comments(ev_id,text,name,email)
{
var comment=text;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",             
    url:'index.php?option=com_excelvision&controller=excelvision&task=subcomment',
    data: {body:comment,eventid:ev_id,name:name,email:email},
    success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data)
    }
});
}
</script>
<?php 
JHTML::_('behavior.modal'); 

?>
<div class="jointhe">
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root();?>templates/excel/images/conv_icon.png">
<a href="<?php echo JURI::root().'index.php?option=com_excelvision&view=comment&tmpl=component1&ev_id='.$_REQUEST['ev_id'];?>" class="modal" >Join The Conversation</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="prev_comment">

<div id="com_det1">
    <div id="com_det">
        Commnets is loading.......
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**comment.php**

```
<a onclick="window.parent.comments('<?php echo $_REQUEST['ev_id']?>',$('.commnenttext').val(),$('#name').val(),$('#email').val());window.parent.SqueezeBox.close();" class="button_org">Submit Commnet</a>
```

In the above code I call the view layout `commentframe` from `iframe` in `index.php` and in  `iframe` there is a link for comment when clicks on the link light box will open inside the iframe and it's have a link for post the comment when click on it , It should call the commnents function which I defined in the `commnetframe.php`. I tried to do it `window.parent.myfunctionname()` but it's not working. if someone have any solution please help.

Comment: Strange.. `parent.myfunctionname()` has to works. Did you call that function inside the `success` of that ajax request?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown No, I call the function from lightbox which is inside the iframe and define that function in the iframe source,which is commnetframe.php.